# Powershell + Robocopy Auto backup executing multiple times

Tags: powershell, backup, robocopy

I've put together this script to detect file changes in a directory, so that whenever the changes take effect the file(s) changed will get backed up right away.

I have also set up an email notification.

The backup works. I can see whenever a file changes it gets copied over to the desired destination, however I am receiving three emails and the robocopy log shows no changes, which leads me to think it's being written three times each time a file changes. So the last time it gets written there will of course be no changes.

Below you can see the code, hope you can help me figure out what's going on.

```
#The Script
$folder = 'C:\_Using Last Template Approach\' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
$filter = '' # You can enter a wildcard filter here.

# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $false if required. 
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier AutoBackUp -Action {
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
$datestamp = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d@%H-%M-%S"
$Computer = get-content env:computername
$Body = "Documents Folders have been backed up"
robocopy "C:\_Using Last Template Approach" G:\BackUp\  /v /mir /xo /log:"c:\RobocopyLog.txt"
Send-MailMessage -To "me@me.com" -From "jdoe@me.com" -Subject $Body -SmtpServer "smtp-mm.me.com" -Body " "


# To stop the monitoring, run the following commands (e.g using PowerShell ISE:
# Unregister-Event AutoBackUp
}
```

Comment: I wonder if Robocopy is somehow triggering this.. Also you do not do anything with `$changeType` perhaps the answer is in there and a simple if will solve it for you.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for your reply. I can use the additional variables in the body of the email to get more details about the file change event. If I run the the two last lines of the script alone, that is, the robocopy and the Send-MailMessage, I will get just one email as expected and the robocopy log will show that it actually copied or deleted one file, depending on what I did with any of the files in the source directory. It is like those two lines are being executed once for each level of the source directory tree.

Comment: Someone else could chime in but I am just changing one line in a file and the trigger is firing twice for me. Will investigate. I'm not using robocopy or send mail. just a simple write host

Comment: This firing multiple times is apparently a common occurance... googling "filesystemwatcher triggered twice" comes up with a lot of results.

Comment: Worth reading... Look at the comments as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940516/why-does-filesystemwatcher-fire-twice. Also things like notepad trigger twice in how they save their file. This could just be how your system changes files.

Comment: Thanks again Matt. This certainly has to do with how  the FileSystemWatcher class looks at the changes in the Fs. I will see how can I work around it and get robocopy to run just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do not change your monitor script just change send mail and copy with copy-item powershell command

```
$folder = 'c:\sites' # Enter the root path you want to monitor. 
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 

# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.                           
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'} 
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action { 
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore white 
Out-File -FilePath c:\sites\filechange\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
$username=”gmailaccount”
$password=”password”
$smtpServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $username, $password )
$msg.From = "gmail"
$msg.To.Add(“mail should check notify”)
$msg.Body=”Please See archive for notification”
$msg.Subject = “backup information”
$files=Get-ChildItem “c:\sites\filechange\”
Foreach($file in $files)
{
Write-Host “Attaching File :- ” $file
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList S:\sites\filechange\$file
$msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)
}
$smtp.Send($msg)
$attachment.Dispose();
$msg.Dispose();
Copy-Item c:\sites\$name C:\a\$name }
```

i check this script work for me if change file content of file first email log file then copy them to destination c:\a\ also you and that file changed to attachment of mail

Comment: Hi Soheil. Thanks for your reply. I will give it a try, though I need to keep the two copies of the whole directory tree synchronized, that's why I'm using robocopy. I'll let you know when I test your scripts. Thanks again.

Comment: @Martin you can copy multiple file just first you should use get-childitem then piped all file to copy-item like `get-childitem -path "SOURCE\PATH" -filter *.txt -recurse | copy-item -destination "DESTINATION\PATH"`