# Is there a simple way to avoid or stop FileSystemWatcher raise event twice in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I want to know what how to avoid or stop `FileSystemWatcher` raise event twice in C#? I have a solution that will detect everytime if there is newly created xml file from a folder. I test my application using creating xml file using notepad but from the listbox it displays twice.

How can I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            listBox1.Items.Add(e.FullPath);
        }

        finally
        {
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogSelectFolder = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogSelectFolder.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = true;
        fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        fileSystemWatcher1.Path = textBox1.Text;
        fileSystemWatcher1.Filter = "*.xml";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        textBox1.Text = "";
        fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you asked this a few hours ago (and you deleted it), and I linked to the SO answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileSystemWatcher Changed event is raised twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice)

Comment: @MitchWheat, yes i tried the link you gave me but it does not work, I already implemented the code i found there in my code :(

Comment: @Sui Go even in this iteration of your question you still left out the portions of the code where you actually handle the `FileSystemWatcher` events.

Comment: @QuintinRobinson, that's all my code sir

Comment: It's better to write `if(dialogSelectFolder == DialogResult.OK)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have stumbled upon this problem myself twice and i created a class that helps you get only one event at a time. You might also get false events when the file is not in read mode (such as when you copy a file).

You have to create a queue and store all events there and if a time interval passes then raise the appropriate event.

Unfortunately this is not a simple function thus i will include complete code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace menelabs.core
{
/// <summary>
/// This class wraps FileSystemEventArgs and RenamedEventArgs objects and detection of duplicate events.
/// </summary>
internal class DelayedEvent
{
    private readonly FileSystemEventArgs _args;

    /// <summary>
    /// Only delayed events that are unique will be fired.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _delayed;


    public DelayedEvent(FileSystemEventArgs args)
    {
        _delayed = false;
        _args = args;
    }

    public FileSystemEventArgs Args
    {
        get
        {
            return _args;
        }
    }

    public bool Delayed
    {
        get
        {
            return _delayed;
        }
        set
        {
            _delayed = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool IsDuplicate(object obj)
    {
        DelayedEvent delayedEvent = obj as DelayedEvent;
        if (delayedEvent == null)
            return false; // this is not null so they are different
        FileSystemEventArgs eO1 = _args;
        RenamedEventArgs reO1 = _args as RenamedEventArgs;
        FileSystemEventArgs eO2 = delayedEvent._args;
        RenamedEventArgs reO2 = delayedEvent._args as RenamedEventArgs;
        // The events are equal only if they are of the same type (reO1 and reO2
        // are both null or NOT NULL) and have all properties equal.        
        // We also eliminate Changed events that follow recent Created events
        // because many apps create new files by creating an empty file and then
        // they update the file with the file content.
        return ((eO1 != null && eO2 != null && eO1.ChangeType == eO2.ChangeType
            && eO1.FullPath == eO2.FullPath && eO1.Name == eO2.Name) &&
            ((reO1 == null & reO2 == null) || (reO1 != null && reO2 != null &&
            reO1.OldFullPath == reO2.OldFullPath && reO1.OldName == reO2.OldName))) ||
            (eO1 != null && eO2 != null && eO1.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created
            && eO2.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Changed
            && eO1.FullPath == eO2.FullPath && eO1.Name == eO2.Name);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This class wraps a FileSystemWatcher object. The class is not derived
/// from FileSystemWatcher because most of the FileSystemWatcher methods
/// are not virtual. The class was designed to resemble FileSystemWatcher class
/// as much as possible so that you can use FileSystemSafeWatcher instead
/// of FileSystemWatcher objects.
/// FileSystemSafeWatcher will capture all events from the FileSystemWatcher object.
/// The captured events will be delayed by at least ConsolidationInterval milliseconds in order
/// to be able to eliminate duplicate events. When duplicate events are found, the last event
/// is droped and the first event is fired (the reverse is not recomended because it could
/// cause some events not be fired at all since the last event will become the first event and
/// it won't fire a if a new similar event arrives imediately afterwards).
/// </summary>
internal class FileSystemSafeWatcher
{
    private readonly FileSystemWatcher _fileSystemWatcher;

    /// <summary>
    /// Lock order is _enterThread, _events.SyncRoot
    /// </summary>
    private readonly object _enterThread = new object(); // Only one timer event is processed at any given moment
    private ArrayList _events;

    private Timer _serverTimer;
    private int _consolidationInterval = 1000; // milliseconds

    #region Delegate to FileSystemWatcher

    public FileSystemSafeWatcher()
    {
        _fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        Initialize();
    }

    public FileSystemSafeWatcher(string path)
    {
        _fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
        Initialize();
    }

    public FileSystemSafeWatcher(string path, string filter)
    {
        _fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path, filter);
        Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the component is enabled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>true if the component is enabled; otherwise, false. The default is false. If you are using the component on a designer in Visual Studio 2005, the default is true.</value>
    public bool EnableRaisingEvents
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = value;
            if (value)
            {
                _serverTimer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                _serverTimer.Stop();
                _events.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the filter string, used to determine what files are monitored in a directory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The filter string. The default is "*.*" (Watches all files.)</value>
    public string Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileSystemWatcher.Filter;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileSystemWatcher.Filter = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether subdirectories within the specified path should be monitored.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>true if you want to monitor subdirectories; otherwise, false. The default is false.</value>
    public bool IncludeSubdirectories
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the size of the internal buffer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The internal buffer size. The default is 8192 (8K).</value>
    public int InternalBufferSize
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type of changes to watch for.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>One of the System.IO.NotifyFilters values. The default is the bitwise OR combination of LastWrite, FileName, and DirectoryName.</value>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">The value is not a valid bitwise OR combination of the System.IO.NotifyFilters values.</exception>
    public NotifyFilters NotifyFilter
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the path of the directory to watch.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The path to monitor. The default is an empty string ("").</value>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">The specified path contains wildcard characters.-or- The specified path contains invalid path characters.</exception>
    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileSystemWatcher.Path;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileSystemWatcher.Path = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the object used to marshal the event handler calls issued as a result of a directory change.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke that represents the object used to marshal the event handler calls issued as a result of a directory change. The default is null.</value>
    public ISynchronizeInvoke SynchronizingObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a file or directory in the specified System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Path is changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event FileSystemEventHandler Changed;
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a file or directory in the specified System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Path is created.
    /// </summary>
    public event FileSystemEventHandler Created;
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a file or directory in the specified System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Path is deleted.
    /// </summary>
    public event FileSystemEventHandler Deleted;
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the internal buffer overflows.
    /// </summary>
    public event ErrorEventHandler Error;
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a file or directory in the specified System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Path is renamed.
    /// </summary>
    public event RenamedEventHandler Renamed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Begins the initialization of a System.IO.FileSystemWatcher used on a form or used by another component. The initialization occurs at run time.
    /// </summary>
    public void BeginInit()
    {
        _fileSystemWatcher.BeginInit();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Releases the unmanaged resources used by the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher and optionally releases the managed resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Uninitialize();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Ends the initialization of a System.IO.FileSystemWatcher used on a form or used by another component. The initialization occurs at run time.
    /// </summary>
    public void EndInit()
    {
        _fileSystemWatcher.EndInit();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Changed event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs that contains the event data.</param>
    protected void OnChanged(FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Changed != null)
            Changed(this, e);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Created event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs that contains the event data.</param>
    protected void OnCreated(FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Created != null)
            Created(this, e);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Deleted event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs that contains the event data.</param>
    protected void OnDeleted(FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Deleted != null)
            Deleted(this, e);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Error event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">An System.IO.ErrorEventArgs that contains the event data.</param>
    protected void OnError(ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Error != null)
            Error(this, e);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Renamed event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A System.IO.RenamedEventArgs that contains the event data.</param>
    protected void OnRenamed(RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Renamed != null)
            Renamed(this, e);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// A synchronous method that returns a structure that contains specific information on the change that occurred, given the type of change you want to monitor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="changeType">The System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes to watch for.</param>
    /// <returns>A System.IO.WaitForChangedResult that contains specific information on the change that occurred.</returns>
    public WaitForChangedResult WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes changeType)
    {
        //TODO
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// A synchronous method that returns a structure that contains specific information on the change that occurred, given the type of change you want to monitor
    /// and the time (in milliseconds) to wait before timing out.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="changeType">The System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes to watch for.</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">The time (in milliseconds) to wait before timing out.</param>
    /// <returns>A System.IO.WaitForChangedResult that contains specific information on the change that occurred.</returns>
    public WaitForChangedResult WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes changeType, int timeout)
    {
        //TODO
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation

    private void Initialize()
    {
        _events = ArrayList.Synchronized(new ArrayList(32));
        _fileSystemWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(this.FileSystemEventHandler);
        _fileSystemWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(this.FileSystemEventHandler);
        _fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(this.FileSystemEventHandler);
        _fileSystemWatcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(this.ErrorEventHandler);
        _fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(this.RenamedEventHandler);
        _serverTimer = new Timer(_consolidationInterval);
        _serverTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.ElapsedEventHandler);
        _serverTimer.AutoReset = true;
        _serverTimer.Enabled = _fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents;
    }

    private void Uninitialize()
    {
        if (_fileSystemWatcher != null)
            _fileSystemWatcher.Dispose();
        if (_serverTimer != null)
            _serverTimer.Dispose();
    }

    private void FileSystemEventHandler(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        _events.Add(new DelayedEvent(e));
    }

    private void ErrorEventHandler(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        OnError(e);
    }

    private void RenamedEventHandler(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        _events.Add(new DelayedEvent(e));
    }

    private void ElapsedEventHandler(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // We don't fire the events inside the lock. We will queue them here until
        // the code exits the locks.
        Queue eventsToBeFired = null;
        if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(_enterThread))
        {
            // Only one thread at a time is processing the events                
            try
            {
                eventsToBeFired = new Queue(32);
                // Lock the collection while processing the events
                lock (_events.SyncRoot)
                {
                    DelayedEvent current;
                    for (int i = 0; i < _events.Count; i++)
                    {
                        current = _events[i] as DelayedEvent;
                        if (current.Delayed)
                        {
                            // This event has been delayed already so we can fire it
                            // We just need to remove any duplicates
                            for (int j = i + 1; j < _events.Count; j++)
                            {
                                if (current.IsDuplicate(_events[j]))
                                {
                                    // Removing later duplicates
                                    _events.RemoveAt(j);
                                    j--; // Don't skip next event
                                }
                            }

                            bool raiseEvent = true;
                            if (current.Args.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created || current.Args.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
                            {
                                //check if the file has been completely copied (can be opened for read)
                                FileStream stream = null;
                                try
                                {
                                    stream = File.Open(current.Args.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
                                    // If this succeeds, the file is finished
                                }
                                catch (IOException)
                                {
                                    raiseEvent = false;
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    if (stream != null) stream.Close();
                                }
                            }

                            if (raiseEvent)
                            {
                                // Add the event to the list of events to be fired
                                eventsToBeFired.Enqueue(current);
                                // Remove it from the current list
                                _events.RemoveAt(i);
                                i--; // Don't skip next event
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // This event was not delayed yet, so we will delay processing
                            // this event for at least one timer interval
                            current.Delayed = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_enterThread);
            }
        }
        // else - this timer event was skipped, processing will happen during the next timer event

        // Now fire all the events if any events are in eventsToBeFired
        RaiseEvents(eventsToBeFired);
    }

    public int ConsolidationInterval
    {
        get
        {
            return _consolidationInterval;
        }
        set
        {
            _consolidationInterval = value;
            _serverTimer.Interval = value;
        }
    }

    protected void RaiseEvents(Queue deQueue)
    {
        if ((deQueue != null) && (deQueue.Count > 0))
        {
            DelayedEvent de;
            while (deQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                de = deQueue.Dequeue() as DelayedEvent;
                switch (de.Args.ChangeType)
                {
                    case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed:
                        OnChanged(de.Args);
                        break;
                    case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:
                        OnCreated(de.Args);
                        break;
                    case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted:
                        OnDeleted(de.Args);
                        break;
                    case WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed:
                        OnRenamed(de.Args as RenamedEventArgs);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

}
```

You may find the code at:
https://github.com/melenaos/FileSystemSafeWatcher/blob/master/FileSystemSafeWatcher.cs

Comment: Please don't link to external sites as your answer. Always put the content in the answer directly and only link to support the that content.

Comment: Self Promotion Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See:  [What signifies “Good” self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)

Comment: @Enigmativity I am not really sure why is this better that the link but here you go!

Comment: @MenelaosVergis - It's entirely possible for the external link to become dead one day. There are too many possible ways that that can happen. If the code is on this site then it will last as long as this site does. That's why.

Comment: @MenelaosVergis Please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444370/filesystemsafewatcher-missing-files-copied