# FileSystemSafeWatcher Missing Files Copied

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, filesystemwatcher, system.io.file

I'm currently using [FileSystemSafeWatcher](https://github.com/melenaos/FileSystemSafeWatcher) to overcome issues caused by File System Watcher. (Ref:[Is there a simple way to avoid or stop FileSystemWatcher raise event twice in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438190/is-there-a-simple-way-to-avoid-or-stop-filesystemwatcher-raise-event-twice-in-c))

When trying to monitor a folder for copied event of around approx 400 images,Only approx 300 events are triggered.Files can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bcmQw4P79p9FCS2E0k_UKr5hKiQLZCgQ/view?usp=sharing

I cannot understand what causes this issue.

Copied event

```
void copied(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
       // Printing to check if the If condition causes the issue
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("||| > " + robotprocesslist.Count);

   if (ImageExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath).ToUpperInvariant()))
            {
              try
                {

                    if (processedfiles.Any(sublist => sublist.Contains(e.FullPath)) == true)
                    {
                        processedfiles.Remove(e.FullPath);
                    }
                    robotprocesslist.Add(e.FullPath);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("--> " + robotprocesslist.Count);


                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {

                }


            }

        }
```

Hooking to the Copied Event

```
 watcher = new FileSystemSafeWatcher(@watchpath);
 watcher.ConsolidationInterval = 500;
 watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 watcher.Created += copied;
 watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;
```

Comment: I would prefer if this was a GitHub issue, I will work on that after the summer vacations

Comment: @MenelaosVergis okay ... I will post on Git.Are you aware of this issue?

Comment: No, I don't use this that much nowdays. My first thought is that it might be a windows thing, have you used the official `FileSystemWatcher` to see if this is happening? If yes then you have to find the root of the problem in windows docs

Comment: @MenelaosVergis The official file system Watcher works fine in this case.