# Event triggered fired twice

Tags: c#, events

I'll try my best to explain my situation.

I'm developing a software using C#, which allows multiple users to edit the same file under a common directory at the same time and see the changes others make too.

So I used FileSystemWatcher to monitor the changes in the file (to update others' changes) and  textchanged of the textbox (to save changes to the file so others' screen would be updated too).

It's working if I input characters (both events are fired once)
It's not working if I try to delete characters in any form (backspace, delete, etc) It won't delete any character and the cursor always gets reset to position 0. I used box.SelectionStart to move the cursor and it's working when I input characters.

I put a counter kinda thing to check and I found that when I tried to delete characters, both events are fired twice.

I tried to search but I got mixed answers...

Thanks in advance

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;`enter code here`
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Threading;

    namespace SharedFileEditor
    {
        public partial class EditorView : Window
        {
            private EditorModel model;
            private FileSystemWatcher watcher;
            private string path;
            private int count = 0;
            private int count2 = 0;

            public EditorView()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                model = new EditorModel();
                this.DataContext = model;
            }

            private void OpenClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
                {
                    dialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
                    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dialog.FileName), "*.txt");
                        Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dialog.FileName));
                        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                        path = dialog.FileName;
                        HandleOpen(dialog.FileName);
                    }
                }
            }

            internal void HandleOpen(string path)
            {
                FileStream f = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(f);
                model.Content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }

            private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
            {
                if (this.Box.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FileStream f = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(f);
                        model.Content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        this.Box.CaretIndex = model.Cursor;
                        reader.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine("read:" + count2++);
                    }
                    catch (IOException x)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Box.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    new updateContent(OnChanged), source, e);
                }
            }

            private void ContentChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                FileStream f = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(f);
                writer.Write(this.Box.Text);
                model.Cursor = this.Box.SelectionStart;
                model.Content = this.Box.Text;
                writer.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("write:"+count++);
            }

            public delegate void updateContent(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What 'both events'. Please show some code.

Comment: What event are you using and what `NotifyFilters` are you using on the `FileSystemWatcher`

Comment: codes added...there're some craps

Comment: Note: you should be disposing those `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` when your done or you are going to run into file access problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out... it has something to do with how my application works. Solved by setting the EnableRaisingEvents flag to false and back to true later.

Answer (score 1):

I think the actual answer to your question is contained in this post:
[FileSystemWatcher Changed event is raised twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice)

To summarize, this is a bug in the `FileSystemWatcher` class. The save process often occurs in batches. Your `FileSystemWatcher` class picks them all up.

Comment: From the post link you give I understand it's no bug in FileSystemWatcher. If an application writes several times to disk it's expected to be caught several times as well