# Powershell monitoring for file system changes

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-2.0

I want to do some things when there is a change in a bunch of folders (like send an email).  It is working more or less. The problem is I am getting too many notifications. I know I can hack it and keep track and ignore dups, but it seems like there should be a way to get it to work normally.

Code:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "s:\Reporting\Report Output Files\"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action {
write-host "Changed: $($eventArgs.FullPath)"
}
$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action {
write-host "Created: $($eventArgs.FullPath)"
}

while($true) {
start-sleep -s 2
}
```

Results when I create a file:

```
Created: s:\Reporting\Report Output Files\IT\Scheduled_IO.log
Changed: s:\Reporting\Report Output Files\IT\Scheduled_IO.log
Changed: s:\Reporting\Report Output Files\IT\Scheduled_IO.log
Changed: s:\Reporting\Report Output Files\IT\Scheduled_IO.log
Changed: s:\Reporting\Report Output Files\IT
```

I'm not sure why I am getting 3 changes (I can see why I am getting a directory level change) when really it was just a file being created.  When I change a file, I am also getting dup changes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice

Comment: Looks like I do have to hack it. Thanks.