# C# FileSystemWatcher Event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, event-handling, file-watcher

I have to follow changes of one of folder.

```
class FileWatcher
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void StartWatching()
    {
        watcher.Path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Read test data";

        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;            

        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
     }

    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Changes in folder: 'Read test data' ");           
    }
}
```

And initialization:

```
private FileWatcher watch = new FileWatcher();

    private void StartReadCVSChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        watch.StartWatching();
    }
```

For some reason when I do have some changes the event handler is called 3 times:

[image]

I prefer it to be once.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe it would be worth handling the different events from different methods rather than just handling it from a single one? As per the example on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher(v=vs.110).aspx - Also check the change type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice)
Text from there.

> You may notice in certain situations that a  single creation event
>   generates multiple Created events that are handled by your component.
>   For example,if you use a FileSystemWatcher component to monitor the
>   creation of new files in a directory,and then test it by using Notepad
>   to create a file, you may see two Created events generated even though
>   only a single file was created. This is because Notepad performs
>   multiple file system actions during the writing process. Notepad
>   writes to the disk in batches that create the content of  the file and
>   then the file attributes. Other applications may perform  in the same
>   manner.Because FileSystemWatcher monitors  the operating system
>   activities, all events that these applications  fire will be picked up