# ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript, and frankly, I may be doing this wrong. But...I'm trying to create a "KeyUp Listener" for text-boxes that will "notify" when the user has stopped typing.  However, when I try to register the class, I get the following error:

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed
>   because of error: ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined

**REGISTRATION:**

```
// MODULES
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// COMPONENTS
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/shared/components/shared-header.component';
import { SampleIndexComponent } from './components/samples/sample.index.component';
import { SampleFormComponent } from './components/samples/sample.form.component';
import { StatusFilterComponent } from './components/samples/filters/status-filter.component';
import { AuthorFilterComponent } from './components/samples/filters/author-filter.component';

// LISTENERS
import { TextboxKeyUpListener } from "./components/shared/services/textbox.keyup.listener";

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        SampleIndexComponent,
        StatusFilterComponent,
        AuthorFilterComponent,
        SampleFormComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // <-- Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'samples', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'samples', component: SampleIndexComponent },
            { path: 'form', component: SampleFormComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'samples' }
        ])
    ],
    providers: [AuthorFilterNotifier, StatusFilterNotifier, TextboxKeyUpListener]
})
export class AppModule
{
    constructor() { }   
}
```

**NOTIFIER LOOKS LIKE:**

```
// MODULES
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class TextboxKeyUpListener {

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    constructor(private textbox: HTMLInputElement)
    {
        this.init();
    }

    // PROPERTIES - private
    private typingTimer: NodeJS.Timer;
    private typingTimerInterval: number = 1000;
    private notifyDoneTyping = new Subject<string>();

    // PROPERTIES - public
    public notifyDoneTyping$ = this.notifyDoneTyping.asObservable();

    // METHODS - public
    private keyUp(ev: KeyboardEvent)
    {
        global.clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
        if(this.textbox.value)
            this.typingTimer = global.setTimeout(this.notify, this.typingTimerInterval);
    }

    // METHODS - private
    private init()
    {
        this.textbox.onkeyup = this.keyUp;
    }

    private notify()
    {
        this.notifyDoneTyping.next(this.textbox.value);
        console.log("Done Typing")
    }
}
```

Comment:  v aesthetic code style

Answer (score 6):

Some time ago I had a problem in having Typescript recognize some basic DOM classes, which has been solved adding

```
"lib": [
  "es2016",
  "dom"
]
```

to tsconfig.json file

I am not sure this can help your case, but it may be worth trying

==========================================================================

**ADDITIONAL THOUGHTS TRIGGERED BY THE COMMENTS CHAIN - NOT RELATED TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION**

***Use of debounce Rx operator to signal end-of-typing***

If you need to signal end of typing in a simple and elegant way, you may want to consider to use **Rx** and the `debounce` operator. The idea is to create an Observable out of the event stream coming from the Front End element (in your case the Input element I guess) and use `debounce` to have an event emitted if no new value has been received from the input stream within a specified amount of time. You can look at these links for more details ([What does RxJS.Observable debounce do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840247/what-does-rxjs-observable-debounce-do), https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html) - many more examples are available online

***Communication among components***

I understand you have 2 components that need to communicate. Specifically the **"listener"** needs to tell the **"other component"** that typing is finished.

If the **"other component"** always contains the **"listener"** you may use `@Output` to define output events that the **"listener"** can emit and the **"other component"** can listen to.

If the **"listener"** is not contained by the **"other component"**, then the use of a service to communicate can be considered even if you have to also consider that services are Singletons (at least within their scope). Being a Singleton means that if you have more than one Input field you want to listen to for end-of-typing, than you need to figure out how to map the Singleton service with the many Inputs.

In case the UI is complex, you can consider to use a central store as per redux pattern (redux store pattern is available in Angular through https://github.com/ngrx/store or https://github.com/angular-redux/store - this is an [interesting link](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/) that explains pros and cons of a redux-store based architecture)

Comment: Im sorry...but that is already in my TS.CONFIG...Thanks for the help

Comment: Also...does the "Listener" code look like I am on the right track?

Comment: Now that I look to the code more in details I have a couple of questions (consider that I am not familiar with Universal, so my questions may be very much misplaced). Why is the listener an Injectable (which means something that can be injected as a service into components and/or other services)? Is the intention of the listener to emit if within 1 second no keyUp event is captured?

Comment: That part of the code is TypeScript+Angular2.  Listener may be a misnomer.  The intent is for 2 components to talk to one-another through a Service (which I have named Listener...in this case).  Once the user stops typing = notify.

Comment: I have edited my answer with some details not related to your original question (for which I do not know how help you further) but to other elements that I think may be of interest for you case. I hope they can help

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is actually an `eslint` and not a `typescript` error.

For me it solved completely by adding `browser` to the list of environments on `.eslintrc.js`.

```
{
  ...
  env:    {
    ...
    browser: true,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```