# How can I get multiple services call to finish before emitting an event

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, rxjs

Hello I'm working with angular 5.
What I want to achieve is to wait until multiple services calls finish, I don't know if I can use forkJoin operator because the the service calls depends on a parameter, for example: If this parameter is 2, there will be two calls to this service. Is there a way to get this working somehow?

Code:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this._periodQtty; i++) {
        this.service.getPastMonthData(i).subscribe(pastMonthData => {

            if (pastMonthData && pastMonthData.length > 0) {
                chartPoints = new Array<ChartPoint>();

                pastMonthData.forEach(pastMonthElement => {
                    point = this.buildChartPoint(pastMonthElement, timeSpan);

                    if (point)
                        chartPoints.push(point);
                });

                chartDataSets.push({
                    data: chartPoints,
                    backgroundColor: "#f44336",
                    borderColor: "#ba000d",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "#ba000d",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#ff7961",
                    pointRadius: 3.5,
                    label: "prueba 2",
                    fill: false,
                    type: 'line',
                })
            }

            this._chartDataSets = chartDataSets;
            this.ChartDatasetsUpdated.emit(this._chartDataSets);
            })
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840247/what-does-rxjs-observable-debounce-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might achieve what you want

```js
import { range } from 'rxjs/observable/range';
import { map, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';

const sources$ = range(0, this._periodQtty).pipe(
  map(i => this.service.getPastMonthData(i)),
  toArray()
);
sources$.subscribe(sources => {
  forkJoin(...sources).subscribe(allPeriodsData => {
    allPeriodsData.forEach((pastMonthData, monthIndex) => {
      ...
    });
  });
});
```

Or with array building instead of observable range,

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';

const sources = new Array(this._periodQtty).fill(null).map((x,i) => {
  this.service.getPastMonthData(i)
);
forkJoin(...sources).subscribe(allPeriodsData => {
  allPeriodsData.forEach((pastMonthData, monthIndex) => {
    ...
  });
});
```