# Event called 2 times when file updated, needs to call only ONE time

Tags: c#, file-watcher

I have below code written in C# console app, basically it's watching a folder `Temp` where it will watch for `test.txt` file updates.

```
class Program
{
    private static FileSystemWatcher watcher;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("C:\\Temp\\", "test.txt");
        watcher.Changed += EventCall;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void EventCall(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("update done");
    }
}
```

When `test.txt` file updated, `EventCall` method called 2 times, whats changed needs to be done so that event should called only 1 time?

Comment: Check what files you're getting, for example if I save an excel file, I get 4 events too

Comment: There is No issue while creating file, only 1 time event called, but updated invoke event 2 times. question updated

Comment: manually opening, update and closing file, Is this is the issue?

Comment: even updating grammatically, event fired 2 times.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't avoid it, [32 people didn't solved the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top), think about check the last write time.

Comment: @user584018 Well, if doing an excel file, it seemed to make temp file which while looking in my case for *.xlsx only, it picked up the random.tmp it made, as .xlsx, and so on, hence I said check for the file names.

Answer (score -1):

This below solution is works for me.

```
private int fireCount = 0;
private void inputFileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   fireCount++;
   if (fireCount == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fired only once!!");
        dowork();
    }
    else
    {
        fireCount = 0;
    }
}
```

}