# FileSystemWatcher: aggregate multiple filter events into a single one?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, filesystemwatcher

Take the following code, the events raised by the watcher all call the same method:

```
[NonSerialized]
private FileSystemWatcher Watcher;

private void WatcherInit()
{
    Watcher ??= new FileSystemWatcher();

    Watcher.Path                  = Application.dataPath;
    Watcher.Filter                = "*.mat";
    Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    Watcher.NotifyFilter          = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;

    Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    Watcher.Changed += OnWatcherChanged;
    Watcher.Created += OnWatcherCreated;
    Watcher.Deleted += OnWatcherDeleted;
    Watcher.Renamed += OnWatcherRenamed;
}

private void OnWatcherRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs args)
{
    DoViewReload();
}

private void OnWatcherDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs args)
{
    DoViewReload();
}

private void OnWatcherCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs args)
{
    DoViewReload();
}

private void OnWatcherChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs args)
{
    DoViewReload();
}
```

This results in the same method called multiple times while I'd like it to be only once.

In my case, I refresh the UI and it happens 3 times when I create a new file.

I suppose there should be some timer that would wait for successive events and concat them, then only emit a single call; that's just a guess and maybe there's a better solution around that I'm not aware of.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Watcher.Path                  = Application.dataPath;` Put a breakpoint on this line of code. Run the code. How many times is the breakpoint hit?

Comment: You probably want to coalesce the events into a delay anyway because FSW often raises events while a file is still in use by the program creating it

Comment: In addition to what @CaiusJard wrote, you can also get a changed event raised by accessing the file from your code (last access time changes).

Comment: Is this relevant? [FileSystemWatcher Changed event is raised twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice)

Comment: @mjwills Why would you want this to be hit multiple times ? Initialization is only done once.

Comment: @CaiusJard Yep, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: @Steeeve Yep, got you, I have written a small chart about the events occurring.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That's helpful somewhat.

Comment: @aybe I think you forgot to answer my specific question. A very common cause of this issue is subscribing twice. I was merely trying to establish whether you may have done that.

Comment: @mjwills You made a point, I can confirm that events are only subscribed once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern ended up working well:

```
private void OnWatcherRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs args)
{
    WatcherTimerRestart();
}

private void OnWatcherDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs args)
{
    WatcherTimerRestart();
}

private void OnWatcherCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs args)
{
    WatcherTimerRestart();
}

private void OnWatcherChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs args)
{
    WatcherTimerRestart();
}

private void WatcherTimerRestart()
{
    WatcherTimer.Enabled = false;
    WatcherTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void WatcherTimerCallback(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // do the funky stuff you wanted to execute only once
}
```

**Notes:**

I decided to switch the UI to a specific state like:

> Waiting for I/O to complete...

And in this case, setting the interval to a not too low value such as 3000 ms is better:

- user has time to read the message
- a lower value in practice turns out to not be enough, even on small files and/or an SSD
- `FileSystemWatcher` is slow at raising events

And here's a mini-table about events raised according a user's action:

| User action | Callbacks raised |
| --- | --- |
| Create | Created |
| Delete | Changed, Deleted |
| Rename | Changed, Created, Deleted |
| Move | Changed, Created, Deleted |

You may want to note that, ironically, `Renamed` isn't raised at all even for a rename operation; this probably has to do with how an application renames a file, there are multiple ways to do it.