# CacheItemPolicy expiration happens only on fixed boundaries

Tags: c#, memorycache

Looking for a solution to a FileSystemWatcher issue I found a very interesting solution cited here [FileSystemWatcher Changed event is raised twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1765094) from the original by [Ben Hall](https://failingfast.io/a-robust-solution-for-filesystemwatcher-firing-events-multiple-times/)

Now, my new problem is about a `MemoryCache` object with an expiration set by a `CacheItemPolicy`.

My final code is almost identical to the example above, besides the class that declares those objects. The confusing result is that the `MemoryCache` doesn't expire on the time I set with the property `MemoryCache.AbsoluteExpiration` or `MemoryCache.SlidingExpiration`, but it does so on a fixed **20 seconds boundary**.

What I mean is that if I set something like

```
    private readonly MemoryCache _memCache = MemoryCache.Default;
    private CacheItemPolicy _cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    ...
    private void OnRemoveFromCache(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arguments)
    {
        if (arguments.RemovedReason != CacheEntryRemovedReason.Expired)
            return;
        
        var e = (FileSystemEventArgs)arguments.CacheItem.Value;
        
        //  Process e
        ...
    }

    public void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        _cacheItemPolicy = new()
        {
            RemovedCallback = OnRemoveFromCache,
            AbsoluteExpiration =
                DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMilliseconds(100.0)
        };
        _memCache.AddOrGetExisting(e.Name, e, _cacheItemPolicy);
    }
```

the callback `OnRemoveFromCache` is called *only* on the seconds :00, :20 or :40

That is if my event happens at 12:34:05.000 the callback happens at 12:34:20.000, or if the event is at 12:34:23.000 the callback runs at 12:34:40.000

What is the point I'm missing?

**[EDIT]**
Oh well, as pointed out by @Alberto, here's [Ben Hall](https://failingfast.io/erratic-behaviour-from-net-memorycache-expiration/) dismantling the previous article by... the same Ben Hall! :D

And the same from my own little investigation: `MemoryCache` can only respond with a 20-seconds granularity...

Next question: is there an alternative with a similar pattern and a finer-grained timer or should I bake it myself? :O

Comment: Looks like the 20-seconds granularity is fixed... Shall I build a (simplified!) MemoryCache alike, with a more responsive timer, or is there a ready-to-use alternative?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [this blog post](https://failingfast.io/erratic-behaviour-from-net-memorycache-expiration/) there are 2 ways expired items are evicted from the cache:

- Every 20 seconds, on a Timer
- Whenever an item is accessed if it is expired

Couldn't fine anything in the official documentation btw.

Comment: That confirms my suspicions, as I delved into MemoryCache code... What I found is exactly some 20 seconds granularity. The funny part is that the article you mention is still from Ben Hall: then his own other example is wrong! You can't set a 1-second expiration and expect it to be respected! :D