# Why is powershell script is running twice?

Tags: powershell, shell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script which will execute .exe file on file change in specific directory, but when the change happens, it executes 2 times one after the other.
Can you help me?
Here's the script:

```
$folderToWatch = "C:\Users\user\FTP"
$fileToWatch = "file.txt"  

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $folderToWatch
$watcher.Filter = $fileToWatch
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action = {
    $executablePath = "C:\DotNet\Program.exe"
    $filePath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    Write-Host "New or modified file detected: $filePath"
    Write-Host "Executable path: $executablePath"
    try {
        Start-Process -FilePath $executablePath -Wait
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error starting the process: $_"
    }
}

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Changed -Action $action
```

Comment: Could you possibly have registered it more than once? 
Try `Get-EventSubscriber`

Comment: ```FileSystemWatcher``` is known to fire multiple events sometimes - see https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet/issues/347 or search StackOverflow for "FileSystemWatcher multiple events. It's either a bug, or maybe because the program writing the file is making two separate changes and they're triggering two events. One suggested workaround is to cache the filenames from events and wait to see if another arrives shortly after, and process the "duplicates" as one event - see examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice?page=2&tab=votes

Comment: You are setting the process to Wait which is causing a second event.  I would add to code if status is Wait do nothing instead of calling Start-Process.

Comment: Had this exact issue when clients were using Filezilla to transfer files via ftp to a watched folder.  Some ftp clients 'chunk' the data transfer and basically close the file between chinks, which triggers the watcher process.